# RxSwift properly dispose subscription in closure

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am writing a wrapper around Firebase authentication functions to return `Observable` and add additional `profileIncomplete` state. It basically first checks whether a user is logged in, if so, check whether the user's profile is complete. The following is my code, I wonder whether it is okay to subscribe to an observable in `Observable.create` and, if so, how do I properly dispose the disposable in this case? create a `DisposeBag` inside the closure?

```
enum State {
    case loggedIn
    case profileIncomplete
    case notLoggedIn
}

func listenToAuthState() -> Observable<State> {
    return Observable.create { observable in
        let authStateHandle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener() { [weak self] (_, user) in
            guard let user = user else {
                observable.onNext(.notLoggedIn)
                return
            }
            let disposable = self?.listenToProfileCompleted(uid: user.uid).subscribe(onNext: { (completed) in
                if completed {
                    observable.onNext(.loggedIn)
                    observable.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observable.onNext(.profileIncomplete)
                }
            })
            // How to dispose the disposable???
        }
        return Disposables.create { 
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(authStateHandle) }
        }
}

func listenToProfileCompleted(uid: String) -> Observable<Bool> { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think subscribing inside a `Observable.create` (or inside a different subscribe block) is a code-smell.

It seems you have two separate concerns. `stateChanged` and `profileCompleted`.

I would split those into two different methods, having `listenToAuthState` only in charge of reflecting the result of `addStateDidChangeListener`, and have a separate one for `listenToProfileCompleted`.

This will let you have a separate "ready" (or however you want to call it) that can zip the two. Or otherwise use flatMap, if the auth status must change before you listen to the profile completion.

Answer (score 0):

To dispose resource you can add it to DisposeBag. Like below

```
func listenToAuthState() -> Observable<State> {
    return Observable.create { observable in
        var disposeBag:DisposeBag! = DisposeBag()
        let authStateHandle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener() { [weak self] (_, user) in
            guard let user = user else {
                observable.onNext(.notLoggedIn)
                return
            }
            let disposable = self?.listenToProfileCompleted(uid: user.uid).subscribe(onNext: { (completed) in
                if completed {
                    observable.onNext(.loggedIn)
                    observable.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observable.onNext(.profileIncomplete)
                }
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
            // How to dispose the disposable???
        }
        return Disposables.create { 
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(authStateHandle)
            disposeBag = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea. the DisposeBag will be deallocated when the closure is dead, and might not be as long running as you expect. A DisposeBag needs to be scoped to an owner (like a subscriber), not to a specific method.

Comment: If u think disposeBag will dead, then authStateHandle will also dead!!!

Comment: No, because it’s an escaping closure.